# Keras convolution filter size issue

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, convolution, keras

I'm *very* new to Keras, and in my early experiments I've been encountering an error when I create convolutional layers. When I run this code (found [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#more-examples); "Shared vision model" section)

```
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *
from keras.layers.convolutional import *
from keras.layers.pooling import *

digit_input = Input(shape=(1, 27, 27))
x = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3)(digit_input)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)

mdl = Model(digit_input, x)
```

I get the following error (traceback points to the Convolution2D line):

```
ValueError: Filter must not be larger than the input: Filter: (3, 3) Input: (1, 27)
```

I'd assume I was misusing the interface--especially since no one else seems to have this particular problem--but I pulled the code directly from the Keras docs. The problem persists when I use the `model.add()` syntax. Interestingly though, when I shrink the filter size to 1x1 or increase the number of input channels to 3, the error goes away. I have tried manually setting `dim_ordering='tf'` for the convolution and my keras.json file reads:

```
{
"image_dim_ordering": "tf",
"epsilon": 1e-07,
"floatx": "float32",
"backend": "tensorflow"
}
```

Keras looks like a great tool, but I'm completely unable to use it so far.

P.S. I am using Keras 1.1.0 and Tensorflow 0.10.

Answer (score 2):

'image_dim_ordering' : 'tf' is setting the input's third dimension as the channel input to the 2D Convolution: ie you've currently put a 1x27 input with 27 channels in to be convolved with a 3x3 kernel and no padding.

You should be able to switch 'image_dim_ordering' to 'th' and have this code immediately work. I think 'th' used to be the default and you've unfortunately hit an obsolete tutorial. Here's the Keras documentation from [Convolution2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) - it's there but not particularly prominent:

> dim_ordering: 'th' or 'tf'. In 'th' mode, the channels dimension (the depth) is at index 1, in 'tf' mode is it at index 3. It defaults to the image_dim_ordering value found in your Keras config file at ~/.keras/keras.json. If you never set it, then it will be "tf".

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
digit_input = Input(shape=(27, 27, 1))
x = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, dim_ordering='tf')(digit_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a channel first-last problem. The default is channel last, and if your image will be in the shape (27,27,1) it will work.

```
digit_input = Input(shape=(27, 27, 1))
x = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3)(digit_input)  
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
mdl = Model(digit_input, x)
mdl.summary()
```

You will get:

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(None, 27, 27, 1)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 9, 9, 64)          640       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 4, 4, 64)          0         
=================================================================
Total params: 640
Trainable params: 640
Non-trainable params: 0
```